# building nao_driver through ccmake .. and it could not found naoqi_libqi

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to build naoqi_driver package through ccmake .., and while configuring I am getting this error.
kindly help as I am new to this.
.......................................................................................................
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "naoqi_libqi" with
any of the following names:

```
 naoqi_libqiConfig.cmake
 naoqi_libqi-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "naoqi_libqi" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"naoqi_libqi_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"naoqi_libqi" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223238/building-nao_driver-through-ccmake-..-and-it-could-not-found-naoqi_libqi/) by [shrutichandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/12296/shrutichandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-29**:
Do you have the naoqi_libqi package installed?

**Comment by [shrutichandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/12296/shrutichandra/) on 2015-12-30**:
Could you  send me the link to install.  I could only find libqi_release which does not have cmakelist.txt, so I could not build it. :/

**Comment by [shrutichandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/12296/shrutichandra/) on 2015-12-30**:
Hey, I found it.

**Comment by [awesomebytes](https://answers.ros.org/users/4672/awesomebytes/) on 2017-04-20**:
Where did you find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I added that package. That package depends on gtest and qibuild. Now I am getting error:

CMake Error at /home/shruti/d-prefix/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:80 (find_package):
By not providing "FindGTEST_MAIN.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"GTEST_MAIN", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GTEST_MAIN" with
any of the following names:

```
 GTEST_MAINConfig.cmake
 gtest_main-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "GTEST_MAIN" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"GTEST_MAIN_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"GTEST_MAIN" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.

Any one knows about it?

---

Originally posted by [shrutichandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/12296/shrutichandra/) with karma: 16 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0